# Удалить элемент из списка с

Tags: c, list

Всё никак не могу понять логику удаления. Вроде как самого удаления как такового не существует (но я могу ошибаться), тогда по какой логике удаляется выбранный элемент из списка.
Можете подсказать как мне решить этот вопрос? Поиск элемента сделала, а само удаление не могу понять ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <clocale>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

char s[50];
int max;
struct Elements {
    char name[50], 
        uv[7], 
        group[15];
};
Elements elem[50];
Elements st;

void sort(FILE* f) {    //сортировка - все выводы будут отсортированы в итоге
    for (int j = 0; j < max; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < max - 1; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(elem[i].name, elem[i + 1].name) > 0)
            {
                st = elem[i + 1];
                elem[i + 1] = elem[i];
                elem[i] = st;
            }
        }
    }
}

void full(FILE* f) {    //полный список
    printf("---------------------------------\n");
    printf("  Отсортированный полный список\n");
    printf("---------------------------------\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        printf("%-12s %-7s %s\n", elem[i].name, elem[i].uv, elem[i].group);
    }
}

void one_group(FILE* f) {   //список по группе
    printf("  Введите группу:\n"
        "    Проводник\n    Полупроводник\n    Изолятор\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", &s);
    printf("---------------------------------\n");
    printf(" Отсортированный список по группе\n");
    printf("---------------------------------\n");
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if (strcmp(elem[i].group, s) == 0) {
            printf("%-12s %-7s %s\n", elem[i].name, elem[i].uv, elem[i].group);
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 0) printf("  Вещества не найдены");
}

void one_elem(FILE* f) {    //вывод одного элемента
    printf("  Введите название элемента:\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", &s);
    printf("---------------------------------\n");
    printf("         Поиск элемента\n");
    printf("---------------------------------\n");
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if (strcmp(elem[i].name, s) == 0) {
            printf("%-12s %-7s %s\n", elem[i].name, elem[i].uv, elem[i].group);
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 0) printf("  Вещество не найдено");
}

void del_elem(FILE* f) {    //удаление одного элемента
    printf("  Введите название элемента:\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", &s);
    printf("---------------------------------\n");
    printf("         Поиск элемента\n");
    printf("---------------------------------\n");
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        if (strcmp(elem[i].name, s) == 0) {

            //удаление

            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 0) printf("  Вещество не найдено");
}

int main() {
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    printf("Введите имя файла:\n");
    char fname[125];
    gets_s(fname);
    FILE* f1;
    if ((f1 = fopen(fname, "a+")) == 0)
        printf("Файл не найден\n");
    else {
        printf("            Исходный список\n");
        printf("---------------------------------\n");
        printf("Название     Уд.вес  Проводимость\n");
        printf("---------------------------------\n");
        int i = 0;
        while (fscanf(f1, "%s%s%s", elem[i].name, &(elem[i].uv), elem[i].group) != EOF) {
            printf("%-12s %-7s %s\n", elem[i].name, elem[i].uv, elem[i].group);
            i++;
        }
        max = i;
        sort(f1);
        printf("\nВыберите вариант нужного вывода:\n  "
            "  1) Отсортированный полный список\n  "
            "  2) Вещества введенной группы\n  "
            "  3) Поиск вещества\n  "
            "  4) Вещества одной группы не больше указанного уд.веса\n  "
            "  5) Удаление вещества\n");
        int ch;
        scanf("%d", &ch);
        switch (ch) {
        case 1:full(f1); break;
        case 2:one_group(f1); break;
        case 3:one_elem(f1); break;
        case 4:group_and_uv(f1); break;
        case 5:del_elem(f1); break;
        default:printf("Некорректный ввод"); break;
        }
    }
}
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Перенести все элементы, которые находятся после удаляемого на одну позицию влево.

Comment: Значительно упрощает жизнь контейнеры. В Вашем случае подойдёт vector, в интернете много материала по этому поводу. Очень простыми словами, вектор — это массив, размер которого можно менять прямо по ходу программа

Comment: + где здесь С++?

Comment: ой, ещё плохо понимаю разницу между ними...

Comment: А не подскажете как именно это сделать? И как я понимаю, при дальнейших действиях после каждого удаления нужно будет выводить список размером -1 за каждый удалённый? Тогда же он не удалённый, а просто в конце списка... или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: @МаринаМоросенко если Вам нужна такая логика, то лучше сразу создать второй массив и перенести в него все, что есть в первом, кроме удаленного символа. И все, задача решена. Понятное дело, что это не очень оптимально по ресурсам, но если у вас это учебный пример или список маленький, и вы не можете по какой-то причине использовать контейнеры, то это Ваш вариант.

Comment: Метка С. Какие контейнеры? Для еды?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Когда в цикле найдем объект для удаления, то необходимо перенести все элементы после него на одну позицию влево. Также нужно не забыть отразить изменение размера (уменьшить переменную `max`).
По идее так (код не компилировал):

```
// удаление
for (int j = i; j < max - 1; j++)
{
    elem[j] = elem[j + 1];
}
max--;
```